# Merge Array Objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I have been trying make this following array

```
[
    {
        "name": "Study",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about Java?",
                "answer": "Yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Song",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about song?",
                "answer": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about rock?",
                "answer": "No"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

To this

```
[
    {
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about Java?",
                "answer": "Yes",
                "name": "Study"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about song?",
                "answer": "Yes",
                "name": "Song"
            },
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about rock?",
                "answer": "No",
                "name": "Song"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried to `map` to two arrays ( from `name` and `questions`) and tried to combined them , but I can't make it work for multiple arrays in `questions`. How can I make this ? Is there any `loadash` way too accomplish this easily. But I'm trying to do this in Vanilla JavaScript way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with double `.map()`:

```js
let input = [
    {
        "name": "Study",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about Java?",
                "answer": "Yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Song",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about song?",
                "answer": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "question": "Would you Love to learn about rock?",
                "answer": "No"
            }
        ]
    }
]

let result = input.map(({name, questions}) => ({ questions: questions.map(q => ({name, ...q })) }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
let arr1 = [
    {
      "name": "Study",
      "questions": [
        {
          "question": "Would you Love to learn about Java?",
          "answer": "Yes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Song",
      "questions": [
        {
          "question": "Would you Love to learn about song?",
          "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "question": "Would you Love to learn about rock?",
          "answer": "No"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  arr1.map((element, index) => {
    console.log(element); console.log(index); return
    {
      questions: element.questions.map((e, i) => {
        console.log(e); console.log(i); return {
          ...e,
          name: element.name
        };
      })
    }
  })
```